# About the Pasting Lemma

Tags: general-topology, continuity

From the book of Munkres (Theorem 18.3): Let $X=A∪B$, where $A$ and $B$ are closed in $X$. Let $f:A→Y$ and $g:B→Y$ be continuous. If $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x∈A∩B$, then $f$ and $g$ combine to give a continuous function $h:X→Y$, defined by setting $h(x)=f(x)$ if $x∈A$, $h(x)=g(x)$ if $x∈B$.

In the proof given in the book, it is showed that for any arbitrary closed set $V$ in $Y$, $h^{-1}(V)$ is also closed in $X$. However, I want to prove the lemma by showing for any arbitrary open set $U$ in $Y$, $h^{-1}(U)$ is also open in $X$.

My attempt is as follows:

Let $U∈T_{Y}$, we need to show $h^{-1}(U)∈T_{X}$.

First, we know that if $c:X→Y$ is continuous, and M is a subspace of X, then the restricted function $c_{A}: A→Y$ continuous.

Now;

1. if $h^{-1}(U)⊆A$ and  $h^{-1}(U)⊄B$, then $h^{-1}(U)=f_{A/B}^{-1}(U)∈T_{A/B}$ as $f_{A/B}:A/B→Y$ is continuous.
2. if $h^{-1}(U)⊆B$ and  $h^{-1}(U)⊄A$, then $h^{-1}(U)=f_{B/A}^{-1}(U)∈T_{B/A}$ as $g_{B/A}:B/A→Y$ is continuous.
3. if $h^{-1}(U)⊆A∩B$, then $h^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(U)=g^{-1}(U)∈T_{A∩B}$ as $g_{A∩B}=f_{A∩B}:A∩B→Y$ is continuous.

For 1): We know $B$ is closed in $X$ so $X/B=A/B$ is open in $X$. We also know  $f_{A/B}^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A/B$ by the continuity of $f$. Then, by subspace topology $f_{A/B}^{-1}(U)$ is also open in $X$ s.t $f_{A/B}^{-1}(U)∈T_{X}$. Hence, $h^{-1}(U)∈T_{X}$.
For 2) We know $A$ is closed in $X$ so $X/A=B/A$ is open in $X$. We also know $g_{B/A}^{-1}(U)$ is open in $B/A$ by the continuity of $g$. Then, by subspace topology $g_{B/A}^{-1}(U)$ is also open in $X$ s.t $g_{B/A}^{-1}(U)∈T_{X}$. Hence, $h^{-1}(U)∈T_{X}$.
For 3) We also need to show $h^{-1}(U)∈T_{X}$. However, $A∩B$ is closed in $X$. So, we cannot just directly say that $f_{A∩B}^{-1}(U)=g_{A∩B}^{-1}(U)∈T_{X}$ is open in $X$ by using subspace topology s.t $h^{-1}(U)∈T_{X}$.

If anyone could provide an explanation as to where I am making a mistake or how I can proceed from here, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to prove the lemma using explicitly open sets. I mean, once you know that the preimage of a closed set is closed it is sufficient to say the followig: Let $U$ be an open set in $Y$. The $Y/U$ is closed in $Y$. This implies that $h^ {-1}(Y/U)$ is closed in $X$. Thus $h^ {-1}(U)=X/h^ {-1}(Y/U)$ is open in $X$, which proves the assertion.

Comment: Thank you for your kind remark. I completely understand the proof by using closed sets. I just want to prove it in a different way and it should be possible as proving the continuity by using closed sets is equivalent to proving it using  open sets. So, I just want to see how it works when using open sets.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note is that the cases you created are not correct. It is not possible for $h^{-1}(U) \not \subset A,B$. The preimage can certainly be empty on the closed subsets, but that is about it; all of our inputs come from either subset $A$ or $B$.

Breaking down your proof for case 1, you say:

1. $B$ is closed in $X$.
2. By 1, $X\setminus B = A\setminus B$ is open in $X$.
3. Since the restriction of a continuous function by a subset is continuous, point 2 implies $(f\vert_{A\setminus B})^{-1}(U)$ is open in the open set $A\setminus B$ viewed as a subspace.
4. By subpace topology, $(f\vert_{A\setminus B})^{-1}(U) = h^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

So, I think you mean to say $h^{-1}(U) \cap B = \emptyset$; the preimage of $U$ under $h$ only has members in $A$. Case 2 is handled by swapping $A$ with $B$, and $f$ with $g$. Case 3 translates to saying that $h^{-1}(U)$ has members in $A$ and $B$. If try to reason through what we've done, the first thing to note is that we solved case 1 and case 2 by rewriting $h$ as the restriction of a continuous function restricted to an open set. We cannot do the same thing with this case 3, as you have seen.

To prove case 3, we need the following:
\begin{align}
h^{-1}(U) &= \\
(h\vert_A)^{-1}(U) \cup (h)^{-1} \vert_B(U)  &= \\
(f^{-1}(U) \cap A) \cup (g^{-1}(U) \cap B)
\end{align}
To have any hope of saying our preimage $h$ is open, we need $f^{-1}(U)$ and $g^{-1}(U)$ to be open in $X$ in all cases. This is not possible, suppose $U = Y$. Then, $f^{-1}(U) = f^{-1}(Y) = A$. The subspace topology then tells us that $A$ is open in $A$, which is trivially true by the definition of the subspace topology. There is no way to tell if the closed subset $A$ is open without more information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are correct about the first and the second case. Those are what I meant. But, I could not completely get what you mean by saying h−1(U) is open in X directly. f−1(U) and g−1(U) are not open in X, as A and B are not open in X. I think, that solution can apply to proving by using closed sets. Or I could not see how it works that f−1(U) and g−1(U) are open in X.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Sorry about that, really dumb mistake on my part. What I should have said is that this method cannot prove that $f^{-1}(U)$ and $g^{-1}(U)$ are open in $X$. Take $U=Y$, $f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(Y)=A$ tells us that "A is open in A", which is no more information than we started with. It is impossible to tell that $f$ is continuous solely with open sets without more information e.g. A,B being open.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your endeavour.